# $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"], where is it stored in the Captcha div element? How to handle Recaptcha with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, captcha

I have a simple form which sends an AJAX call to a script that e-mails a message. I previously just had a plain form submit and it worked fine, but when transitioning to using AJAX, one of the `$_POST` parameters, `'g-recaptcha-response'`, I can't seem to grab.

```
<form action="./scripts/sendEmail.php" id="emailform" method="post">
    <textarea id="mess" rows="10" cols="50" name="message"></textarea> <br/><br/>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="..."></div> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

`sendEmail.php` accepts two `$_POST` values: `'message'` and `'g-recaptcha-response'`. The AJAX is as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#emailform').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            method: $form.attr('method'),
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                message: $('textarea#mess').val(),
                g-recaptcha-response: //???
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I've tried a couple of values for the commented `//???`, such as `$('input#recaptcha-token').val()`, since `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']` on `sendEmail.php` matches this token, but I still get errors when submitting.

> Notice: Use of undefined constant success - assumed 'success' in dir\sendEmail.php

`sendEmail.php` is something like below:

```
if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
}
if ($captcha) {
    $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=/*secret*/&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if ($response.success == true) {
        //send e-mail
        exit;
    }
}
//error handling
```

I'm not sure if my problem is grabbing `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']` or something else. Changing the value to `""` pops the same error.

I wanted to reiterate that it all works dandy without AJAX. I don't get an error message, `response.success` is treated as it should.

Comment: Open up the developer tools, navigate to the code inspector, find the element in question and scan around until you find something.

Comment: @TinyGiant, this is where I got some ideas from, but none of them work. Do you perhaps know if there's a way to determine where a $_POST value comes from? Perhaps I could do something like `getFrom($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"])` which would return the id of the element that submitted it.

Comment: `$('input[name="g-recaptcha-response"]').val()`, but I don't know about g recaptcha, so that might not work for any number of reasons.

Comment: I figured it out. It was in a textarea, not input element. I previously tried this and it didn't work, but enclosing the `g-recaptcha-response` in quites (`'g-recaptcha-response'`) made it work. JQuery is weird.

Comment: Post an answer detailing how you solved your problem and anything someone else may need to know if they are facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. `g-recaptcha-respone` was stored in a text area (`textarea#g-recaptcha-response`), which I had tried earlier without success. It turns out it was an error in JQuery: `g-recaptcha-response:$('textarea#g-recaptcha-response').val()` didn't work because the `$_POST` variable needs to be without hyphens (???). Encasing it in quotes made it work and everything is smooth.